# how can i pass the encrypted data through redirect

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect

I have to access a function through redirect

i use this code

```
   function email_check()
{

    $email=$this->input->post('email');
    $data = array(
        'user_email' =>$email, 
        );
   $result = $this->UM->email_verify($data);
   echo $result;
   if($result)
   {

       $date   = date(Y-m-d);
       $string = $email."-".$date;
       $encrypted_string = md5($string);
       echo $encrypted_string;
       $res=$this->UM->insert_key($encrypted_string,$result);
       redirect(base_url()."user/pass_confirmation/".$encrypted_string.'/'.$email); 
     }
   }
```

But not working

Whats the problem here

```
     redirect(base_url()."user/pass_confirmation/".$encrypted_string.'/'.$email);
```

this link is correct but view page is not displayed in the function
I have a doubt that is am passing an email through url

Without this display my view page

I think this a different question i am asking how to pass an encryped key and email through redirect

Comment: Whats not working over here. Can you please elaborate

Comment: quotes problem... use ` redirect(base_url()."user/pass_confirmation/".$encrypted_string."/".$email);`

Comment: I have a function named pass_confirmation.In that load aview page inside the function that is not displayed

Comment: Or `redirect(base_url()."user/pass_confirmation/$encrypted_string/$email"); `

Comment: my error is this "The URI you submitted has disallowed characters."

Comment: So you are using in uri something that is not allowed,Can you share your uri structure ?